# android, анимация

Tags: android

Возник вопрос, каким способом можно реализовать подобный слайдбар

[image: Изображение]

Comment: есть идея такое реализовать с tablayout и viewpager, но мне кажется, что это не правильный подход

Comment: tablayout и viewpager - нормальное решение